# Statement ignored error while inserting data

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am writing procedure to insert data to one table by fetching data from another table. While inserting the data an error occurs (SQL Statement ignored) and (in this place, this column is forbidden). Can you suggest what I am doing wrong

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE KOL2
       IS
       CURSOR CUR IS SELECT empno, ename, SUM(SAL) sal FROM EMP where job = 
        'MANAGER';
      nr_kier NUMBER; nazwisko_kier varchar(20); suma_pensji int; 
      ostatnia_mod date;
    BEGIN
    OPEN CUR;
    LOOP
    FETCH CUR INTO nr_kier, nazwisko_kier, suma_pensji;
    EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
    INSERT INTO statystyka_kierownikow (nr_kier , naziwsko_kier, 
       suma_pensji, ostatnia_mod)
    VALUES (nr_kier, nazwisko_kier, sal, sysdate);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR;
    COMMIT;
     END;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the complete and exact error message. How exactly are you calling that procedure?

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is time consuming task. It is not even suitable for SQL.  You are trying to fetch every record and make insertion one-by-one.

Check my solution below.

```
 INSERT INTO statystyka_kierownikow 
    (nr_kier , naziwsko_kier, suma_pensji, ostatnia_mod)
       SELECT empno, ename, SUM(SAL) sal 
       FROM EMP where job = 'MANAGER'
       GROUP BY empno, ename;
```

Comment: Thank You for reply! I did it your way, and after inserting those 3 values, I insert sysdate to ostatnia_mod column. Now there is other problem:
while execution it says: "not a single-group group function"

Comment: can you please check again